# Drupal Black Box of Death

Tags: 8, database

[image]

Does anyone know what it means when drupal appears to fail but displays this black box in the browser?

Comment: That's produced by [Symfony VarDumper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html); why you're seeing it is pretty difficult to say without access to the code, but look for usages of the `dump()` function (in PHP and Twig)

Comment: So, in theory, the SQL provided in it is because dump(statement) is being called, likely after the SQL failed to run on the DB

Comment: It could be, but I just looked and there doesn't seem to be a call to `dump` anywhere in core code that could result in a `Statement` being dumped. It could be hidden behind layers of calls I guess, but I don't ever recall the same thing happening to me on plenty of D8 sites I've built, even when there are DB errors. I'd be tempted to search for `dump` in the draggable views module to start with, that seems to be the catalyst

Comment: Thank you for that tip, surprisingly i can't find a `dump` statement inside the module.

Comment: Don't suppose you have the [VarDumper](https://www.drupal.org/project/vardumper) or [Twig VarDumper](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper) modules installed?

Comment: I do not. The mystery dump!

Comment: Bug in draggable Views?

Comment: I've determined that the cause of this was actually the dd() statement i had directly beneath the call to the drupal SQL query parser. What's returned in the black box of death I believe is the correct result, but dd() was causing the BBOD. Still not clear on why